# Contour integration of a Bessel function using the Hankel function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, bessel-functions

I'm trying to evaluate the following integral involving the Bessel function of zeroth order and first kind
\begin{equation}
I=\int_0^\infty dx\frac{x J_0 (bx)}{x^2-a^2-\mathrm{i}0^+}\,.
\end{equation}
My approach is to use the relationship between the Bessel and Hankel functions (8.476 6 in  Gradshteyn & Ryzhik )
\begin{equation}
J_0(x)=\frac{1}{2}[H_0^{(1)}(x)-H_0^{(1)}(-x)]
\end{equation}
to write the integral over the whole real line
\begin{equation}
I=P.V.\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\frac{x H_0^{(1)} (bx)}{x^2-a^2-\mathrm{i}0^+}\,.
\end{equation}
Here I have introduced the principle value to avoid the logarithmic singularity at $x=0$. Since the asymptotic form of the Hankel function is
\begin{equation}
H_0^{(1)} (z)\sim\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}(z-\pi/4)}\,,
\end{equation}
it seems like we can use contour integration by closing the contour with a semi-circle in the upper half complex plane, since this contribution will vanish by Jordan's lemma. Given that the small semi circle avoiding the logarithmic singularity at $x=0$ vanishes as well, what remains is the residue contribution from the pole at $x=a+\mathrm{i}0^+$, and thus the integral is given
\begin{equation}
I=\int_0^\infty dx\frac{x J_0 (bx)}{x^2-a^2-\mathrm{i}0^+}=\mathrm{i}\pi H_0^{(1)}(ab)\,.
\end{equation}
This seems relatively simple but I have never seen a source that follows this approach precisely. Is the method valid or have I missed some subtleties?

Comment: You have to be careful what you mean by $-x$ inside the Hankel function, since the function is multivalued. I assume it is $e^{\pi i} x$, x>0.

Comment: What on earth is $\mathrm{i}0^+$ ?

Comment: Looks like is a Hankel Transform: $$\text{HankelTransform}\left[\frac{1}{x^2-a^2},x,b\right]=-\frac{2
   G_{2,0}^{0,2}\left(-\frac{4}{a^2 b^2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right)}{a^2 b^2}$$ Mathematica code: `-((2 MeijerG[{{0, 0}, {}}, {{}, {}}, -(4/(a^2 b^2))])/(a^2 b^2))`

Comment: The method is perfectly valid. Let $f(x) = x/(x^2 - a^2 - i \epsilon)$, $\epsilon > 0$. We have $J_0(x) = (H_0^{(1)}(x) - H_0^{(1)}(-x))/2$ for $x > 0$, where $H_0^{(1)}(-x)$ is the limit from above (in the direction $-i$) of the [principal branch](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2.E5). Therefore
$$J = \int_0^\infty J_0(x) f(x) \, dx =
\frac 1 2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty H_0^{(1)}(x) f(x) \, dx$$
(taking the p.v. is redundant). Since the integrand is continuous from above on the real line,
$$J = \pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{x = \sqrt {a^2 + i \epsilon}}
 H_0^{(1)}(x) f(x).$$

Comment: Late to the party, but I'll also add that this should be perfectly fine. Watson's "A Treatise on the Theory of Bessel Functions" (1922) derived generalizations of this integral using this exact method (see section 13.51, equation 4).

Answer (score 2):

Without certainty, I'd say that the expression $H_0^{(1)}(-x)$ is ill-defined for $x < 0$, since $H_0^{(1)}(x) = J_0(x) + {\rm i}Y_0(x)$ and, while $J_0(x)$ can be extended along the x-axis as an even function, the same can't be said about $Y_0(x)$, which is ill-defined for $x < 0$. I have stumbled upon the expression $H_0^{(1)}(-x)$ for $x > 0$ in several textbooks, however it is always used as a notation to refer to $-H_0^{(2)}(x)$. That being said, and without even getting into the discussion of how to properly extend the integration limits from $(0,\infty)$ to $(-\infty,\infty)$ given that the Hankel functions have a logarithmic singularity at $x = 0$, I believe that the integration cannot contain the negative x-axis due to the integrand being ill-defined - you would probably need to define a different contour. If I were in your shoes, I'd simply follow the usual path of treating the integral as the Hankel transform of $(x^2 + \gamma^2)^{-1}$, with $\gamma = -{\rm i}(a + {\rm i}0^+)$. Interestingly, this approach and your approach yield the same result, however I am positive that the process of getting to this final result is incorrect in your case.

EDIT: I've added a few more information on the Hankel transform I talked about. From Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, 2007, Eq. 6.532.4 reads

$$ \int_0^{\infty}{\frac{xJ_0(ax)}{x^2 + k^2}dx} = K_0(ak) $$

for $a > 0$ and $Re(k) > 0$. In your case, the result is $K_0(\gamma b)$, or, after taking the limit to $0^+$, $K_0(-{\rm i}ab)$.