# Infinite integral of zero order Bessel function and polynomial denominator

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, polynomials

During some calculations in condensed matter physics I have encountered an integral involving the first kind Bessel function of zero order

$$I \sim \frac{1}{r} \int_0^{\infty}{dq~\frac{q J_0(qr)}{(q^2-q_1^2)(q^2-q_2^2)}},$$

where $r > 0$ and $q_1 = k_1 + i0^+$, $q_2 = k_2 - i0^+$ are the integrand's poles, with $k_1, k_2 > 0$. The only way I can think of evaluating this integral is by contour integration, however I first need to address two problems:

a) The integrand is an odd function and as a result cannot be trivially extended from $(0,\infty)$ to $(-\infty, \infty)$ and

b) even if we were to bypass this problem, the numerator involves an oscillating function that does not allow us to use Jordan's lemma, by taking a semicircle with infinite radius on the $Im(q) > 0$ half-plane as a contour.

The only similar thread I've found around is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3941351/contour-integration-of-a-bessel-function-using-the-hankel-function), where the Bessel function is replaced by Hankel functions via

$$J_0(qr) = \frac{1}{2}\left[H_0^{(1)}(qr) - H_0^{(1)}(-qr)\right]. $$

However, I'm uncertain on whether this approach is valid, due to the Hankel functions being multivalued.

A similar integral with $q^3$ in the numerator also appears in my study, but I'm certain that the approach will be similar to the one presented above.

Any thoughts or advice will be greatly appreciated, so thank you in advance.

Comment: To avoid the problem of multivaluedness, one can use http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.4.E4 instead. I do not know if that makes the problem easier though.

Comment: Dear Gary, thanks for your reply. This was my first thought, but unfortunately it doesn't get me any further with the evaluation of the integral via contour integration. It still does not allow me the extension to the $(-\infty, \infty)$ domain.

Comment: @Gary The key point is that $H_0^{(1)}(-x + i0) = H_0^{(1)}(x) - 2 J_0(x)$ (for $x > 0$) for the principal branch of $H_0^{(1)}$, so the steps described in the linked question will work (I tried to clarify some points in the comment below that question). Here we obtain
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_0^\infty
 \frac {q J_0(q)}
 {(q^2 - (k_1 + i \epsilon)^2) (q^2 - (k_2 - i \epsilon)^2)} dq = \\
\frac {\pi i} {2 (k_1^2 - k_2^2)} (H_0^{(1)}(k_1) + H_0^{(2)}(k_2)).$$